# Online database that can be read and modified with python

Tags: python, database, tkinter

I am currently developing a desktop application with python (v3.8) and tkinter and I would like to use a database that would sync certain settings with all users of the application and the changes that the users make would also be saved to the database. However, if I use a local database like SQLite, it would not be synced with all the users. So, I searched online but couldn't find any that suits my need. Is there anyway to do this?

Here is an example of the code where I would like to use such a database (not the actual code though as it is too long):

```
from tkinter import *

home = TK()

Text = #Here I would like to get the value from an online database

l1 = Label(home,text = Text)
l1.pack()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: all the users? you might need an remote sql server for that and mysql has a connector to connect bw database and python code

Comment: Thanks I will look into that.

Comment: you can use external server (in internet) even with SQLite but it would need own code to share it so better use MySQL or Postgress. SO your problem is only external server.

Comment: BTW: many server providers have databases in offer - [Google](https://cloud.google.com/products/databases), `Amazon`, `Microsoft`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your desired need by using `mysql-connector`. Here is how to install it

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

and then import it like

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
```

and you can use it like, following:

```
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector as mysql

home = Tk()

con = mysql.connect(host='',user='',password='',database='') #establish connection by giving appropriate details
c = con.cursor() # A cursor fetches or does queries for you 
c.execute('SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME') #execute the command
text1 = c.fetchall() #collect the information as a list

l1 = Label(home,text = text1)
l1.pack()
```

If you want to share your data with others, then you have to connect to a remote server, where the user and pass and database is given by a host like [db4free](https://db4free.net) or any other sites and the data remains with people having access to it.